# remote docker commands execution

Tags: docker, daemon

Now I have two laptops (not necessary in one local network) and docker installed on both of them. My goal is to run docker daemon on the first laptop and be able to execute commands using docker client on the second laptop. What should I do to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the public API?   [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/)

Comment: how to make one laptop be visible to another one over the network?

Answer (score 2):

Setup Docker to listen for TCP connections on a specified port and protect that port with TLS.  You must setup some environment variables so the Docker client communicates with the Docker daemon.

Here's the relevant documentation:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Enjoy, and have fun.

Comment: a problem is how to make one laptop be visible to another one?

Comment: That would be the topic for another question.  You can configure your modem & router to allow traffic on that port, or setup a VPN, etc.